# Highcharts Drilldown upto n levels

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to drill down in highcharts upto 3 levels(as of now). But it flashes an error saying `SyntaxError: missing : after property id data =  [{`. Where I'm going wrong?

```
$(function () {

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{      // at this line the error shows up.
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data =  [{
                          y : 45.11,
                          color: colors[0],
                          drilldown : {
                            name:'praful',
                            categories:['a','b','c','d'],
                            data:[1,2,3,4]
                          }
                        }],

                    }
                }, {
                    y: 2.14,
                    color: colors[4],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Opera versions',
                        categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                        data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                        color: colors[4]
                    }
                }];

        function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
      chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
      chart.series[0].remove(false);
      chart.addSeries({
        name: name,
        data: data,
        color: color || 'white'
      }, false);
      chart.redraw();
        }

        var chart = $('#column_with_drill_down').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                    setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                                } else { // restore
                                    setChart(name, categories, data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: colors[0],
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.y +'%';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var point = this.point,
                        s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                    if (point.drilldown) {
                        s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                    } else {
                        s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: name,
                data: data,
                color: 'white'
            }],
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        })
        .highcharts(); // return chart
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSLint - it really helps to avoid that errors.

This :

```
categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
data =  [{ ...
```

should be changed to

```
categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
data :  [{ ...
```

Comment: Ooops.. A typo . Thanks.

1 more question. In highcharts, I can only drill-down. I can only  drill-up when I'm at the bottom most level and that too at the top level. Can I drill-up at any specific level?

Comment: Drill down in Highcharts is only example how to use API, it's not some magic code ;)  If you want to go to specific level, use `setChart()` function from code above with specified drill down level.